# How do I use headers included in a dll in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-errors

Apprently this shouldn't be happening, but I have a dll that includes `SDL2.h`. It compiles fine, but when I use the client project (a project linked to the dll) it gives the error

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDL.h'. No such file or directory.
```

I included the correct header, dll and lib files for the dll. Inside the dll, I included the correct source files. So why am I getting nonsense errors?

Edit: The include in the dll is inside the header file included in the client project.

Comment: In the program that uses your dll did you setup the include path for SDL if you have `#include "sdl.h"` in any header that the user of your dll will use

Comment: ***I included the correct header, dll and lib files for the dll. Inside the dll*** A dll does not contain or archive headers.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes. That's why I'm so confused about the error. I included everything right in the dll and used SDL functions, but everything compiled fine. Now when I include the dll header, that header is now inaccessible.

Comment: ***Now when I include the dll header, that header is now inaccessible*** Make sure the dll header does not include SDL.h, If it does you have to add the include path to SDL in your client application.

Comment: @drescherjm So what you're saying is that a dll built with functions of another library is useless with only its corresponding header, lib, and dll files? That I must include all third party resources AFTER trying to avoid doing so in the first place?

Comment: ok I'll try, but I've done similar things in the past that worked fine

Comment: There are ways to eliminate the dependency depending on what the client program needs access to. On way is using is removing the include and use PIMPL: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

Comment: ***but I've done similar things in the past that worked fine*** As long as you have "#include "SDL.h"` in your dll header that the client uses the client project will have to know where the SDL.h file is.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, I was under the illusion that libraries didn't need extra dependencies because I've only ever used libraries that didn't need them.